# Get part of HTML table

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

I want to take the contents of a Table from a website.

This is the websites source code:

```
 <tr><td><table width='100%'><tr><td valign='top' width='1px' class='GridViewRow1'><img src='/images/pin.gif'></td><td class='GridViewRow1'><a href='Announcements.etc'><b><i>Title num 1</i></b></a><div class='SmallText'>Username</div><div class='SmallText' style='color:#808080;'>date</div></td></tr></table></td></tr>
<tr><td><table width='100%'><tr><td valign='top' width='1px' class='GridViewRow1'><img src='/images/pin.gif'></td><td class='GridViewRow1'><a href='Announcements.etc2'><b><i>Title num 2</i></b></a><div class='SmallText'>username</div><div class='SmallText' style='color:#808080;'>date</div></td></tr></table></td></tr>
```

And so this is my code

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements td = doc.select("td.GridViewRow1");
desc = td.get(0).nextElementSibling().text();
```

The output I get is:

```
Title num 1 username date as a string.
```

I want to get the title only.

Can someone explain to me how to get the title since the title doesn't have a unique tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements td = doc.select("td.GridViewRow1");
desc = td.select("a[href]").first().text();
```

This was the solution to my issue

Comment: You could simplify that to desc = doc.select("td.GridViewRow1 a[href]").first().text();

Answer (score 0):

Title is marked with  - select just that

```
... td = doc.select("td.GridViewRow1 > b >i");
```